# System Console generating NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, exception

I am using System Console to read a line as in below code

```
public class Strings2 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String Name;        
        Console c = System.console();
        Name = c.readLine("%s", "Name?:");

        System.out.println(Name);
    }
}
```

But when i run this its generating a NullPointerException

[image]

Any idea why this happens

I am running the above code in eclipse

Comment: Why -1 to my Question

Comment: Dont worry about the downvote, just see, Jon Skeet is answering your question, how lucky you are !!!

Comment: I got it When i run this in eclipse Its showing null pointer exception But when i run from cmd its working fine Thanks a lot for all those replied and those who downvoted my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your context, System.console() is not available and you should check for null and find an alternative course of action.

> "System.console()
>
> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, if any.
>
> Returns: The system console, if any, otherwise null."

_

> "Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the
>   underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual
>   machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an
>   interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and
>   output streams then its console will exist and will typically be
>   connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine
>   was launched. If the virtual machine is started automatically, for
>   example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have
>   a console. "

Taken from java.sun.com.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, it's behaving as [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29):

> **Returns:**
>   The system console, if any, otherwise null.

There's no console, hence it returns null.

It should be fine if you run it *from a console*... but you should check the return value and take a different course of action if it returns null.

Answer (score 2):

If you're executing that code from Eclipse, you will definitely get that error. Eclipse uses a different stream and you cannot capture the console in that. But the code will work just fine when executed from UNIX shell or Windows/Mac as the underlying OS attaches the console to JVM's resource (your code).

Answer (score 0):

[public static Console console()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console%28%29)

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java
>   virtual machine, if any.
>
> Returns: The system console, if any, otherwise null.

Answer (score 0):

Running a debugger through, c is null when it's returned from System.console();

So the next line throws a null pointer exception.